# What is the first step to solving $\cos3x - \sin x = \sqrt{3}(\cos x - \sin 3x)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

My calculus BC teacher has given us some trig "review".

$$\cos3x - \sin x = \sqrt{3}(\cos x - \sin 3x).$$

How do I get rewrite the cos3x and sin3x? Do I just use sum and difference, because it makes everything really complicated.

can someone teach me how to format this correctly... sorry I am a new user

Answer (score 4):

We have $$\cos3x+\sqrt3\sin3x=\sqrt3\cos x+\sin x$$

$$\iff\cos\left(3x-60^\circ\right)=\cos\left(x-30^\circ\right)$$

$$\iff 3x-60^\circ=360^\circ m\pm\left(x-30^\circ\right)$$ where $m$ is any integer

Comment: How did you get to the second step?

Comment: consider left hand side of first step divided by 2.  $\frac{1}{2}\cos(3x) + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin(3x)$ = $\cos(60°)\cos(3x) + \sin(60°)\sin(3x)$ = by angle addition identity: cos(3x-60°).  
You can do the same for the right hand side divided by 2.

Comment: Well done! ${}$

Answer (score 0):

$\cos3x - \sin x = \sqrt{3}(\cos x - \sin 3x)$

$\implies \cos3x+\sqrt3\sin3x=\sqrt3\cos x+\sin x$

Now divide both sides by 2 to get :

$\frac{1}{2}\cos3x+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\sin3x=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\cos x+\frac{1}{2}\sin x$

$\implies \cos \frac{\pi}{3} \cos 3x + \sin \frac{\pi}{3} \sin 3x=\cos \frac{\pi}{6} \cos x + \sin \frac{\pi}{6} \sin x$

$\implies \cos(3x-\frac{\pi}{3})=\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{6})$

$\implies 3x-\frac{\pi}{3}=\pi k \pm (x-\frac{\pi}{6}),  k\in\mathbb{Z}$

$\implies x=\frac{\pi}{2} \left( k+\frac{1}{6}\right)  OR $  $ $ $ x=\frac{\pi}{4} \left( k+\frac{1}{2}\right)$